# How can I accept both rvalue and lvalue non-const parameter type

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I'm repeatedly running into the problem of accepting a non-const reference parameter, since it seems taking an rvalue parameter prevents accepting lvalues and vice versa. Here's an example

```
void read(File &file)// I want to modify file
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    file.readInto(&someObject);//readInto is a non-const method
    // do something with the data populated in someObject
}
```

But when I try to call read I have a problem if I try two different calling conventions

```
//this works just fine
File f1 = File::open("some_file_path");
read(f1);

// However this fails
read( File::open("some_file_path") );//because open returns an rvalue
```

The problem I have is if I change the parameter to a non-const rvalue than I can't pass the lvalue anymore. Am I doomed to always provide an override (or template) that takes the rvalue reference type and simply calls out to the lvalue override?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 1):

Since you updated the question, I suggest doing this:

```
void read(File& file)
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    file.radInto(&someObject);
    // ...
}

void read(File&& file) { read(file); }
```

That will handle both lvalues and rvalues with minimal code repetition.

---

I think your `read` function should simply take a `File&`:

```
void read(File& file) // I want to modify file
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    file.readInto(&someObject);//Modifies file
    // do something with the data populated in someObject
}
```

Then you can call:

```
// OK
std::shared_ptr<File> f1 = File::open("some_file_path");
read(*f1);

// OK
read( *File::open("some_file_path") );
```

Added benefit: the function is not limited to `shared_ptr`, and works with any `File` independently of how its memory is managed.

---

Alternatively, use a *forwarding reference*:

```
template <typename T>
void read(T&& file)// I want to modify file
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    file->readInto(&someObject);//Modifies file
    // do something with the data populated in someObject
}
```

Comment: You're right. I updated the question to delete the shared_ptr part, but the question remains the same.